# Android find a view after it is inflated

Tags: android

I am creating some views programmatically using `ViewStubs`, as shown below.

```
RelativeLayout allCommissionsContainer = (RelativeLayout) mBaseLayout.findViewById(R.id.allCommissionsContainer);

        ViewStub viewStubCommission = new ViewStub(mActivity);

        viewStubCommission.setLayoutResource(R.layout.viewstub_commission_container);
        allCommissionsContainer.addView(viewStubCommission);

        viewStubCommission.inflate();
```

But how do I find that inflated view (a `RelativeLayout`) later in the code? If I use `viewStubCommission.setTag("MyTag");` won't it be applied to the actual `ViewStub` and not the inflated View? I tried this but it gave me a `null pointer exception`.

I need something like `allCommissionsContainer.findViewById(R.id.someId)` or `allCommissionsContainer.findViewWithTag("MyTag")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing I realized I can use

```
RelativeLayout myRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) viewStubCommission.inflate();
```

and then set a tag or id

```
myRelativeLayout.setTag("MyTag");
```